# AWS S3 Select get data for column with a / in the name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I am trying to use [S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html)  to query some data from a CSV file on S3 using the following query:

```
aws s3api select-object-content \
--bucket <bucket> \
--key <key> \
--expression "select `lineItem/intervalUsageStart` from s3object limit 100" \
--expression-type 'SQL' \
--input-serialization '{"CSV": {}, "CompressionType": "NONE"}' \
--output-serialization '{"CSV": {}}' "output.csv"
```

However, this fails with:

```
An error occurred (ParseUnExpectedKeyword) when calling the SelectObjectContent operation: Unexpected keyword found, KEYWORD:from at line 1, column 9.
```

I believe this is because I am using back-ticks to escape the column I want to get data from. If I don’t escape the column name, it fails with the following:

```
An error occurred (LexerInvalidChar) when calling the SelectObjectContent operation: Invalid character at line 1, column 16.
```

I guess this is because of the / in the column name. Is there a way I can get data from this particular column in this file? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I see S3 Select supports fetching columns by index as well (like `_1`, `_2` for the first, second columns, etc.). This would help as well for now. Modifying the above query to:

```
aws s3api select-object-content \
--bucket <bucket> \
--key <key> \
--expression "select _2 from s3object limit 100" \
--expression-type 'SQL' \
--input-serialization '{"CSV": {}, "CompressionType": "NONE"}' \
--output-serialization '{"CSV": {}}' "output.csv"
```

(since `lineItem/intervalUsageStart` is the second column in the CSV) helped resolve the issue.

Comment: what if I want to use such a column in WHERE clause? I tried _10='xyz' and it didn't work i.e. threw the same error.